# Wrapping executable's input and output in c++

Tags: c++

There is a program in java (Minecraft) and for the server part of it, it opens up in a terminal and prompts the user for commands, as well as give feedback for loading progress and other stuff.  How can I make a c++ "wrapper" to automatically send commands to the terminal, and receive the response?

I could automate commands such as say and kick with GUI elements.  I am running a mac with OSX Lion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It presumably reads and writes stdin/stdout.  You should look up executing a binary (in this case java.exe) in c++ and how to read and write to it.  Alternatively, you could write a wrapper in Java that gives you control without having to parse the text output.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put which OS I was running.  Would it be the same if I was running a Mac?

Comment: Yes.  The executable in that case would be /usr/bin/java but the concept is the same.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question would depend on the operating system as different systems use different approach how to deal with the standard input and output channels. On a UNIX system you'd create a pipe(2) (or two if you want to capture standard output and standard error separately), fork(2) the "server", use close(2) and dup(2) to put the various file descriptors into place, and then execve(2) the actual program. After this you can read/write to various descriptors.

Comment: Yikes, that's a lot of...  stuff.  Is there an example that might be available?

Comment: Well, I'd need to either write or google one. Looking at appropriate tags for UNIX and/or POSIX would probably reveal a FAQ over here as well (haven't tried it, though). The key is the "pipe", i.e. that is what I'd look for if I'd try to locate an example.